# $.getJSON don't work in the second link page of my local site

Tags: php, html, json, get, localhost

I have a problem with the `$.getJSON` function. The get works fine on my first page - index.html. However, when I go to my second page - second.html and use the function `$.getJSON` I get an error.

The code (second.html) does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').click(search);
});

function search(){
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    $.getJSON("api/research_name.php?nome="+nome, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This code (index.html) works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').click(search);
});
function search(){
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    $.getJSON("api/research_name.php?nome="+nome, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: what's the error you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this would probably be better as a comment, but)

check your code. you assign `name` to the value of an input field, but in your .getJSON call use `nome`

Also, you should probably use urls that are fully qualified. For example, if your hierarchy is

/index.html

/folder/something/second.html

then your api call will be relative to the directory in which it was called, which might not be the root.

Consider changing it to `"/api/research_name.php?nome="+nome`